# An optimal number of worker threads in an async IO TCP server

Tags: asynchronous, io, boost-asio

We have migrated our thread per connection communication model to an async IO based TCP server using `boost::asio`. The reason for this change is that the old model didn't scale well enough. We have permanently about 2k persistent connections on average with the tendency to keep growing on a monthly basis.

My question is what would be the ideal number of worker threads that will poll the io_service queue for completion handlers - the number of virtual cpu cores?

Choosing a small number can lead to the situations where the server does not consume quickly enough and can't cope with the rate the clients send messages.

Does it make sense to add worker threads dynamically in such situations?

Update: 
Probably it is my implementation but i find this statement part of the boost asio docu confusing:

> *Implementation strategies such as thread-per-connection (which a synchronous-only approach would require) can degrade system
>   performance, due to increased context switching, synchronisation and
>   data movement among CPUs. With asynchronous operations it is possible
>   to avoid the cost of context switching by minimising the number of
>   operating system threads — typically a limited resource — and only
>   activating the logical threads of control that have events to
>   process.*

As if you have X threads pumping completion events on a machine that has X cores - 1) you don't have any guarantees that each thread gets a dedicated cpu and 2) if my connections are persistent i don't have any guarantees that the thread that say does an async_read will be the same as the one to execute the completion handler.

```
void Connection::read {
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 18),
                            boost::bind(&Connection::handleRead, shared_from_this(),
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void Connection::handleRead(const boost::system::error_code &error,
                                               std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    // processing of the bytes
    ...
    // keep processing on this socket
    read();
}
```

Comment: This is clearly impossible to answer except to say "it depends". What I would say is that your ideal design ought to be one, no more than two kernel threads per NIC installed up to NIC bandwidth saturation. If you're exceeding that then you need to refactor your software to not be so inefficient. Read up on how nginx implemented 10 Gbps NIC scalability, or bring in an ASIO consultant expert to advise you.

Comment: People (not necessarily you) tend to greatly underestimate the power of a single thread.  The amount of work a single thread can do is colossal.  The concerns you need to balance are 1) context switching from too many threads causing latency and throughput problems, 2) high latency and poor throughput caused by too few threads pumping completion events, and 3) higher than necessary working set size due to excessive thread stacks causing poor CPU cache performance.  The balance of all these for your workload is the sweet spot, and the only way to find it is to experiment and measure.

Comment: I want to follow up more on this. What we see with the async IO approach is that the latency problems are gone as expected but the absolute number of ctxt switches/second is about 10 times bigger that what we used to have in the thread per connection model. In other words, 24 IO threads pumping completion events produce way more context switches than ~1k worker threads in the old model. Can you please share your thoughts on this?

Comment: @ladaManiak - If your old model was based on polling then it was probably not yielding the processor as much as an async model would, causing more context switches.  I feel like your reduced latency is directly tied to the increase in context switches here - reducing latency generally does add CPU overhead.

Comment: @hoodaticus i tried to elaborate more and edited my initial question.

Comment: @ladaManiak - to give an informed guess as to why you are seeing an increase in context switches we'd need to see the implementation of the old system.  If your latency is down and your throughput is up, I wouldn't worry about context switch overhead.  Just play around with the thread count while measuring throughput and latency until you find the max.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal situation with perfectly non-blocking I/O, a working set that fits entirely in L1 cache, and no other processes in the physical system, each thread will use the entire resources of a processor core.  In such a situation, the ideal number of threads is one per logical core.

If any part of your I/O is blocking then it makes sense to add more threads than the number of cores so that no cores sit idle.  If half the thread time is spent blocked then you should have almost 2 threads per core.  If 75% of the thread time is spent blocked then you should have 3 or 4 per core, and so on.  Context switching overhead counts as blocking for this purpose.

I've noticed that when Microsoft has to make a blind guess about this, they tend to go for two or four threads per core.  Depending on your budget for making this determination I would either go with 2 or 4, or start with one thread per core and work my way up, measuring throughput (requests serviced / second) and latency (min, max, and average response time) until I hit the sweet spot.

Dynamically adjusting this value only makes sense if you are dealing with radically different programs.  For a predictable workload there is a sweet spot for your hardware that should not change much even with increasing amounts of work to be done.  If you are making a general purpose web server then dynamic adjustment is probably necessary.